# Pandas - insert a dataframe to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I am trying to insert a dataframe into MongoDB. Each row should be one document.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd

client = MongoClient()
col = client['test']['test']

d = {'name': ['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
     'age': [22,38,26,35],
     'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05],
     'survived?': [False, True, True, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

col.insert_many(df)
```

However, the above code returns an error: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Changing `col.insert_many(df)` to `col.insert_many(df.to_dict())` or `col.insert_many(df.to_json())` causes `TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping`

Comment: try this: `col.insert_many(df.to_dict('r'))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were very close, we can re-use your code.

Note, we still use [`pymongo.MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) and [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict), with one param added in the latter.
`to_dict(orient='records')`
we would then have

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd

client = MongoClient()  # Remember your uri string
col = client['test']['test']

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Braund','Cummings','Heikkinen','Allen'],
                   'age': [22,38,26,35],
                   'fare': [7.25, 71.83, 0 , 8.05],
                   'survived?': [False, True, True, False]})

data = df.to_dict(orient='records')  # Here's our added param..

col.insert_many(data)
```

In short, by specifying `orient='records'` the output is a list of dicts, the same format accepted by `insert_many`. Also, as a bonus - `to_dict` does better with datetime-type columns as compared to `to_json`!